# how to beginning with GDAL, how can i use it for image format conversions

Tags: gdal

I like to work with GDAL. is it a software with or without graphical user interface?
or the commands are run in command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

GDAL is deeply inside a library but there are many command line tools for vector and raster processing which can be considered to be a part of GDAL. See raster and vector utility programs from http://gdal.org/. However, GDAL is used in large number of programs which may offer graphival user interface to GDAL http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/SoftwareUsingGdal?version=109.

As an example, the raster conversion tool in QGIS is mainly a GUI for the gdal_translate utility http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

[image]